# Break AsyncTaskResult<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> into another list

Tags: android

Is there any way to break AsyncTaskResult>>
into to list ?
or get like 30,40,.. value of it only?

i have a Async class and it return the result of webservice fetch to adapter.
now because of huge data i want to split the result into seperate segment with passing
number of result to async class.

here is myasync class :

```
protected AsyncTaskResult<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
        String... arg0) {

        String xml = "Get String from my web service class"
        myXmlParsingClass myparser = new myXmlParsingClass (xml, "getitem");
        myparser .runParser();

        AsyncTaskResult<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> myresult = new AsyncTaskResult<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>(myXmlParsingClass .getParsedData());

        return myresult ;

    }
```

and my asynctaskresult :

```
public class AsyncTaskResult<T> {
    private T result = null;
    private Exception error = null;

    public T getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public Exception getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public AsyncTaskResult(T result) {
        super();
        this.result = result;
    }

    public AsyncTaskResult() {
        super();
    }

    public AsyncTaskResult(Exception error) {
        super();
        this.error = error;
    }
```

this is what i have done so far :
in the getview method inside my adapter i made second method to pass a number to async class:

```
MyAsyncClass ma = new MyAsyncClass(myview,userid,5);
```

in MyAsyncClass :

```
public MyAsyncClass ( View context,String _id) {
    this.targetCtx = context ;
    id = _id;
}

public MyAsyncClass ( View context,String _id,int _ID_To_Show) {
    this.targetCtx = context ;
    id = _id;
    ID_To_Show= _ID_To_Show;
}
```

and on PostExecute method :

```
if(ID_To_Show >0 ){
     MySecondAdapter Madapter = new MySecondAdapter(targetCtx,        myresult.getResult(),ID_To_Show);
     mylist.setAdapter(Madapter);
   }else{
   MySecondAdapter Madapter = new MySecondAdapter(targetCtx, myresult.getResult());
   mylist.setAdapter(Madapter);
```

and finally in MySecondAdapter i added this :

```
public MySecondAdapter(View a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> id,int _ID_To_Show) {
    idfromhayoolafetch = id;
    myinflater = (LayoutInflater) AppContext.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ID_To_Show= _ID_To_Show;
}
public MySecondAdapter(View a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> id) {
    idfromhayoolafetch = id;
    myinflater = (LayoutInflater) AppContext.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
public int getCount() {
    if(ID_To_Show>0){
        return ID_To_Show;  
    }else{
    return idfromhayoolafetch.size();
    }
    }
```

this approch show the amount of item i want to show in each call and i can pass value to it 
but is other way i can do this ? 
problem is i cant ask hayoola to limit the value in respond.

Comment: Are you processing Xml data inside the Asyn class

Comment: yes both fetching and parseing will happen in async class

Comment: what is AsyncTaskResult do you have it's implementation?

Comment: ive added AsyncTaskResult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a request should be handled by server it self.
As in server should accept number of items to return and only send that many items.

But still if you want async task to handle it you can do following:

```
protected AsyncTaskResult<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
        String... arg0) {

        String xml = "Get String from my web service class"
        myXmlParsingClass myparser = new myXmlParsingClass (xml, "getitem");
        myparser .runParser();

        AsyncTaskResult<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> myresult = new AsyncTaskResult<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>(myXmlParsingClass .getParsedData());
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result=myresult.getResult();
        myresult.setResult(result.subList(0,maxItems));//maxItems=30 set it while creating async task object
        return myresult ;

    }
```